# JSF multiple ajax event on a single page

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, ajax4jsf

I have the following xhtml page where there is a form where the user have to select the location where he wants to travel; choosing it from a selectionmenu, the panel "Volo" is updated by an action listener and it will contain another selectionmenu where all flights to that location are available. I'd like to select the Hotels and Escursions available between the starting and ending date of the flight, so i used an action listener to update the panel containing the two activities based on the flight chosen. I'd like to know where i'm mistaking and if it's possible to have multiple updates of this kind in a single page.
I post the code of the xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
    <title>Add a Default Package</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">


        <p:panel header="DefaultPackage Form">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="regGrid">

                <h:outputLabel for="Name">Name:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="Name"
                    value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.defpackDTO.name}" />
                <p:message for="Name" />

                <h:outputLabel for="location">Locations Available:</h:outputLabel>

                <h:selectOneMenu for="location" value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.defpackDTO.location}">
                <f:ajax listener="#{addDefaultPackageBean.Search()}" render=":form:Volo" />
                    <f:selectItems id="location" value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.availableLocations}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>


            </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>




            <p:panel header="Voli Disponibili per la location selezionata" id="Volo" rendered="#{addDefaultPackageBean.flag}" >

                <h:outputLabel for="Fly">Volo:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:selectOneMenu for="Fly" value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.fly}">
                <f:ajax listener="#{addDefaultPackageBean.sel()}" render=":form:regularGrid" />
                    <f:selectItems id="Fly" value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.elelisfly}"
                        var="ElementDTO" itemValue="#{ElementDTO.name}"
                        itemLabel="#{ElementDTO.name}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>



            </p:panel>




            <p:panel header="HotelEsc" id="HotelEscursioni">
              <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="regularGrid" rendered="#{addDefaultPackageBean.flagdopo}">   

                <h:outputLabel for="Hotel">Hotel:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:selectOneMenu for="Hotel" value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.hotel}">
                    <f:selectItems id="Hotel"
                        value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.elelishotel}" var="ElementDTO"
                        itemValue="#{ElementDTO.name}" itemLabel="#{ElementDTO.name}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message for="Hotel" />

                <h:outputLabel for="Escursion">Escursioni:</h:outputLabel>
                <f:facet name="header">Clicca su view per vedere i dettagli</f:facet>
                <p:dataTable id="Escursion" var="esc"
                    value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.elelisescursion}"
                    rowKey="#{esc.name}"
                    selection="#{addDefaultPackageBean.selectedEscursions}"
                    selectionMode="multiple">
                    <p:column headerText="Nome">  #{esc.name}  </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Costo">  #{esc.cost}  </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Data Iniziale">  #{esc.startingDate}  </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Data Fine">  #{esc.endingDate}  </p:column>

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-search" 
                             oncomplete="PF('escursionDialog').show()" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:dialog header="Escursion Detail" widgetVar="escursionDialog"
                    width="250" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

                    <p:dataList id="display"
                        value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.selectedEscursions}"
                        var="selectedEsc" type="definition">  
                        Nome: #{selectedEsc.name}, Description: #{selectedEsc.description}    
                    </p:dataList>

                </p:dialog>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
            <p:commandButton value="Add" update="regGrid"
                action="#{addDefaultPackageBean.add()}" />

    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Bean page:

```
package beans;

import java.awt.Event;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

import elementManagement.ElementMgr;
import elementManagementDTO.ElementDTO;
import DefaultPackageManagement.DefaultPackageMgr;
import DefaultPackageManagementDTO.DefaultPackageDTO;


@ManagedBean(name="addDefaultPackageBean") //come viene richiamato 
@ViewScoped
public class AddDefaultPackageBean implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EJB
    private DefaultPackageMgr defpackMgr;
    private DefaultPackageDTO defpackDTO;
    private ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelisfly;
    private ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelishotel;
    private ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelisescursion;
    private ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelis;
    private ElementDTO[] selectedEscursions;
    private String fly;
    private String hotel;
    private boolean flag=true;
    private boolean flagdopo=true;
    private ArrayList<String> availableLocations;
    private ElementDTO flyElem;

    @EJB
    private ElementMgr elemMgr;



    public ElementDTO[] getSelectedEscursions() {
        return selectedEscursions;
    }
    public void setSelectedEscursions(ElementDTO[] selectedEscursions) {
        this.selectedEscursions = selectedEscursions;
    }
    public AddDefaultPackageBean() {        
        defpackDTO = new DefaultPackageDTO();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        this.elelisfly=new ArrayList<ElementDTO>();
        this.elelishotel=new ArrayList<ElementDTO>();
        this.elelisescursion=new ArrayList<ElementDTO>();
        this.setElelis(elemMgr.getAllElements());
        this.availableLocations=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(ElementDTO e:elelis)
        {
                if (this.availableLocations.contains(e.getLocation())==false)
                        {

                         this.availableLocations.add(e.getLocation());  

                        }
        }   
    }


    public String add() {
        this.AssignElemFlyFromSelection();
        this.AssignElemHotelFromSelection();
        this.AssignElemEscursionFromSelection();
        defpackMgr.save(defpackDTO);
        return "/employee/index?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public void sel()
    {
        System.out.print("ehila" );
        this.AssignElemFlyFromSelection();
        this.elelisescursion.clear();
        this.elelishotel.clear();

        for(ElementDTO e:elelis)
        {
             System.out.print("ho un hotel tra gli elementi "+e.getName() );
            if(e.getType().equals("Hotel"))
            {
                 System.out.print("ho un hotel tra gli elementi "+e.getName() );
                if(e.getStartingDate().after(this.flyElem.getStartingDate())&&(e.getEndingDate().before(this.flyElem.getEndingDate())))
                {
                 System.out.print("ho un hotel tra gli elementi con le date giuste"+e.getName());
                    this.getElelishotel().add(e);

                }
            }
            else
            {

            if(e.getType().equals("Escursion"))
            {
                if(e.getStartingDate().after(this.flyElem.getStartingDate())&&(e.getEndingDate().before(this.flyElem.getEndingDate())))
                {

                    this.getElelishotel().add(e);

                }

            }

            }
        }
    this.setFlagdopo(true); 


    }


    public DefaultPackageDTO getDefpackDTO() {
        return defpackDTO;
    }
    public void setDefpackDTO(DefaultPackageDTO defpackDTO) {
        this.defpackDTO = defpackDTO;
    }
    public ArrayList<ElementDTO> getElelisfly() {
        return elelisfly;
    }
    public void setElelisfly(ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelisfly) {
        this.elelisfly = elelisfly;
    }
    public ArrayList<ElementDTO> getElelishotel() {
        return elelishotel;
    }
    public void setElelishotel(ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelishotel) {
        this.elelishotel = elelishotel;
    }
    public ArrayList<ElementDTO> getElelisescursion() {
        return elelisescursion;
    }
    public void setElelisescursion(ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelisescursion) {
        this.elelisescursion = elelisescursion;
    }
    public String getFly() {
        return fly;
    }
    public void setFly(String fly) {
        this.fly = fly;
    }
    public String getHotel() {
        return hotel;
    }
    public void setHotel(String hotel) {
        this.hotel = hotel;
    }

    private void AssignElemFlyFromSelection()
    {
        for (ElementDTO elem:this.elelisfly)
        {
            if(elem.getName().equals(this.fly))
            {
                this.flyElem=elem;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AssignElemHotelFromSelection()
    {
        for (ElementDTO elem:this.elelishotel)
        {
            if(elem.getName().equals(this.hotel))
            {
                this.defpackDTO.getElem().add(elem);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AssignElemEscursionFromSelection()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<selectedEscursions.length;i++)
        {
                this.defpackDTO.getElem().add(selectedEscursions[i]);
        }
    }

   public void Search(){

       String s=defpackDTO.getLocation();
       System.out.print("luogo scelto "+s);
       this.setElelis(this.elemMgr.getAllElementsByLocation(s));
       for(ElementDTO e:elelis)
       {
           System.out.print("aggiungo volo "+e.getName());
           if(e.getType().equals("Flight"))
           {
               this.getElelisfly().add(e);
               System.out.print("aggiungo volo "+e.getName());
           }
       }
       this.setFlag(true);
   }

public ArrayList<ElementDTO> getElelis() {
    return elelis;
}
public void setElelis(ArrayList<ElementDTO> elelis) {
    this.elelis = elelis;
}
public ArrayList<String> getAvailableLocations() {
    return availableLocations;
}
public void setAvailableLocations(ArrayList<String> availableLocations) {
    this.availableLocations = availableLocations;
}
public Boolean getFlag() {
    return flag;
}
public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}
public boolean isFlagdopo() {
    return flagdopo;
}
public void setFlagdopo(boolean flagdopo) {
    this.flagdopo = flagdopo;
}
public ElementDTO getFlyElem() {
    return flyElem;
}
public void setFlyElem(ElementDTO flyElem) {
    this.flyElem = flyElem;
}
}
```

Comment: @BalusC answer it please

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible to `update` multiple `components` in single `command` button.

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" update="regGrid ,anothercomponent,anothercomponent2" />
```

Comment: the problem is that i can't execute the function of third panel in the bean..and i don't know why.The panel that is rendered contains a selectionmenu that in base of the value selected, allows me to render another panel. This is the missing step.